# Mutate inner vector of nested vectors

Tags: rust

I want to mutate an inner vector of a nested vector.
So I got this input: `[[1,2],[3,4]]` and I want to add a 1 to the end of every vector so I get the following result: `[[1,2,1],[3,4,1]]`
I wrote this function, but that does not work. I looked into the result with a debugger.

```
fn add_numbers(mut row_matix: Vec<Vec<i64>>) {
    for mut row in row_matix {
        row.push(1)
    } 
}
```

Comment: Do you understand what it means for a function to take a `mut something: T` argument (here: `mut row_matrix: Vec<Vec<i64>>`)?

Comment: Yes that means I am allowed to mutate the given parameter.

Comment: Sure. Now, what do you want to happen? Do you want your changes to be visible after the function call? Or _in_ the function?

Comment: I think inside the function call would be enough. For it to be visble after the funktion call I could just take in a reference or return the row_matrix right?

Comment: The issue with your signature is that you pass the ownership of the `row_matrix` parameter to the function, so when the function is ended, the vector is deallocated and could not be longher accessed. If you want to pass the ownership, consider to have a return value of the function where you return the vector. But I suppose what you want here is to have a mutable reference to the vector: `row_matrix: &mut Vec<Vec<i64>>`.

Comment: Okay that seems to work, but how would I use the edited `row_matrix` afterwards? I moved it with the for loop.

Comment: @MarioSantini no you don't have to dereference it Rust [automatically dereferences it for you](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c08816a8dabe32a4b88de5e004f5872d).

Comment: Just reborrow it: `for row in &mut *row_matrix`.

Comment: Or even `for row in row_matrix.iter_mut()` which works with owned or exclusively borrowed vectors.

Comment: @cafce25 Rust does auto-deref but I'm not sure this is a case where that happens, since the method takes `&mut self`. Wouldn't it be more accurate to say that in the owned case, `x.push(y)` auto-refs `x`? If you already have a `&mut` then there's no need to auto-deref _or_ auto-ref. With a `&mut`, `(*x).push(y)` will explicitly deref but then auto-ref, no?